# How can I get the average of a percentile in R?

Tags: r

I have a vector of values, and I need to calculate the mean of the 90% worst values in that vector.
I came up with the following (procedural) function:

```
percentile_worst <- function(d, p = 0.9) {
  quant = quantile(d, p)
  worst = c()
  for (t in seq(1, length(d))) {
    if (d[t] <= quant) {
      worst = c(worst, d[t])
    }
  }
  return(mean(worst))
}
```

Is there any more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data is in a data frame, you can do subsetting:

```
mean(d$foo[d$foo < quantile(d$foo, .9), ])
```

Comment: This only works if the only variable in the data frame is "foo". `set.seed(123)`; `d <- data.frame(foo = rnorm(100), x = rnorm(100))`; `mean(d[d$foo < quantile(d$foo, .9), ])`. You need `mean(d$foo[d$foo < quantile(d$foo, .9)])` or `mean(d[d$foo < quantile(d$foo, .9), "foo"])`